# Where can I buy a massive D4?

Tags: dice

Simple question, really.  I've had a look online on ebay, [The Dice Shop](http://www.thediceshoponline.com), a couple of other online stores and just general Googling, but search engines don't seem to be very geared towards buying massive D4s.

Anyone know of a place that sells over-size RPG dice, specifically a 6cm or larger D4?

I've found a few shops that sell large D6s and [large D10 "Cthulhu"](http://www.thediceshoponline.com/dice-search/giant) dice, but none that sell large D4s...

Comment: Hi LordScree. Shopping recommendations are generally frowned on at SE: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Last activity date on that thread is over a year ago. If you feel this thread shouldn't have been closed I would encourage you to state your case in the comments here or Meta (remember: community members with high reputation can vote to reopen it)... But in general you're better off talking about why your post is awesome rather than pointing out other questions that weren't closed (unless there's a ton of them, recently).

Comment: Also -- This is the sort of question that is a good fit for asking on chat.

Comment: Personally, I don't see this as a "shopping" question.  The stack overflow blog, is very clear that the problem with "shopping questions", is that there is all sorts of information you need to make a good answer. In this case, all the answer needs is a few links to show where you can find such a product.  Completely different type of question.

Comment: However, maybe the question can be improved by asking, "What key terms should I search for which will allow me to buy a large d4 die."  And in this case the answer is "plush" or "foam"

Comment: I want the question re-opened too because I want a massive d4. The closest I came was at Gen Con, where they sold 1.5" high d4s made out of quartz. But flaws in the quartz kept me from buying.

Comment: @GMNoob *"In this case, all the answer needs is a few links to show where you can find such a product. Completely different type of question."* -- Okay. But I still have problems with it, for this very reason. As it exists now, it's answerable strictly with a Google search term. [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/the-game-table) is great for getting new search terms to try.

Comment: What I'd like to see out of this question is either a) A more specific use-case than "big freaking dice" (which likely doesn't exist... That's fine), or b) at the very least something that requires the answer to explain a bit about what goes into choosing one. A bunch of Google search words isn't that compelling as far as answers go.

Comment: @AceCalhoon But they likely aren't looking for "plush" or "foam", so some other sort of knowledge might be needed.

Comment: Also, I think demanding that someone be in the right time zone to get an answer on Chat is a bit unfair.

Comment: @GMNoob This is where the specific use-case angle I mention above comes in. The question as is only asks for "bigger than six centimeters, and includes a D4." Even if we assume "for use in play," foam dice still work because the foam "rolls" about as well as a die of that size can.

Comment: @GMNoob Chat persists, so it's entirely possible to get answers in a delayed fashion. No one has to be online at the same time as you to get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

[image]

The Die was found here:

http://www.toyvault.com/gamesupplies/plush.htm

It seems that item is out of stock.. So perhaps this set of [foam dice will](http://www.rpgshop.com/d-and-d-dice-and-bags/specialty-dice/foam-and-plush-dice/jumbo-foam-polyhedral-dice-5.html) work better?

Comment: Thanks @GMNoob.  Seeing as no-one else will ever be able to answer this question, I have accepted yours as the answer :D